What simultaneous H264 live encoding capacity could be expected from RPi4
According to the specifications RPi4 is able to encode 1080p at 30fps and I've ssen benchmarks backing that claim up, but I'm interrested in encoding multiple streams simultaneously. What could then be expected? Would that make two strams at 720p at 30fps? Reasoning that 720p has about half the pixels.

Pretty sure the max value for multiple streams is going to be a straight division of the max value for one stream.
